# Would like NSArray valueForKey to return the array indices

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, key-value-coding

I can create an `NSArray` that contains all the hash values of the objects in `myArray` like this:

```
NSArray *a = [myArray valueForKey:@"hash"];
```

**What key do I pass to `valueForKey:` to get an array containing myArray's indices?**

Say myArray has n items. I'd like to do something like this:

```
NSArray *a = [myArray valueForKey:@"index"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray * arrayWithNumbersInRange( NSRange range )
{
    NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger i;
    for( i = range.location; i <= range.location + range.length; i++ ){
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i];
    }

    return arr;
}
```

---

```
NSArray * indexArray = arrayWithNumbersInRange((NSRange){0, [myArray length]-1});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query an NSArray for the index of an object with `indexOfObject:`

```
NSArray *a = [myArray valueForKey:@"hash"];
NSInteger index = [myArray indexOfObject:a];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Given an array with n objects I'd like to create an array containing the integers `0, 1 ... n-1`.

Comment: They keys of an array are always sequential from 0 -> count - 1  and they're not cocoa objects so there'll be no method that returns what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a superclass of NSArray which returns the index:

```
//
//  CapArrayOfIndex.h
//  Created by carmin politano on 7/26/12.
//  no rights reserved
//

@interface CapArrayOfIndex : NSArray {
    /*! Simulated constant array containing an array of NSNumber representing the index. */
    NSUInteger iCount;
    //*! NSNotFound causes bybass of index bounds testing. */
}
#pragma mark create
+ (CapArrayOfIndex*) withCount: (NSUInteger) aCount;
@end
```

and

```
//
//  CapArrayOfIndex.mm
//  Created by carmin on 7/26/12.
//  no rights reserved
//

#import "CapArrayOfIndex.h"

@implementation CapArrayOfIndex
#pragma mark NSCopying
- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) aZone {
    /*! New allocation required because -count is a mutable property. */
    return [CapArrayOfIndex withCount: self.count];
}
#pragma mark create
+ (CapArrayOfIndex*) withCount: (NSUInteger) aCount {
    CapArrayOfIndex* zArray = self.alloc;
    zArray->iCount = aCount;
    return zArray;
}
#pragma mark NSArray
- (NSUInteger) count {
    return iCount;
}
- (void) setCount: (NSUInteger) aCount {
    iCount = aCount;
}
- (id) objectAtIndex: (NSUInteger) aIndex {
    /*! My code performs a bounds test using unusual macros: return [ViaUInteger RaiseIfObjectAtIndex(nil, self, aIndex, nil)]; */
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger: aIndex];
}
@end
```

Comment: This version has been tested.  It should possible to auto-synthesize property count (remove its instance variable and methods), but I am not using this code at this time (cannot test the modification now).